# How PSExec runs application as SYSTEM user?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-services, createprocess

I wondered how psexec.exe by sysinternals executes a process as a SYSTEM user.
I need to run a tool under a SYSTEM process, but I don't really know how to do that without registering it as a service.

Does anyone have an idea ?

p.s. I would really prefer to do it with WINAPI (C++). Thanks! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`psexec` operates by creating a phantom, behind-the-scenes Windows service named "psexesvc" that is then removed after the operation completes.

Details are here: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/PsExec-Nasty-Things-It-Can-Do.html

Perhaps your tool could call `psexec` to run a process?